# Advise on file encryption performance in Java

Tags: java, performance, encryption

I am doing some file encryption related work. I am able to  encrypt/decrypt the files but facing a major performance issue. When I simply read/write a video file of 700 MB size, my code performs at around 27-28 MB/s. But when I perform encryption(I am currently using PBEWithMD5AndDES, which I would be changing later) code shows speeds at 9 MB/s.
Please advise as to where can I improve.

Code snippet:

```
    int c = 0, BUF_SIZE = 8192;
    byte[] b = new byte[BUF_SIZE];
    FileInputStream fis;
    DataInputStream dis;
    FileOutputStream fos;
    DataOutputStream dos;
    CipherOutputStream cos;


    try {
        // Create PBE parameter set
        pbeParamSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, iterationCount);

        // Create PBE Cipher
        Cipher pbeCipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);

        // get key
        key = generateKeyFromPassword(password);

        // Initialize PBE Cipher with key and parameters
        pbeCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, pbeParamSpec);

        fis = new FileInputStream(inFile);
        dis = new DataInputStream(fis);
        fos = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
        dos = new DataOutputStream(fos);
        cos = new CipherOutputStream(fos, pbeCipher);


        while ((c = dis.read(b)) > 0) {
            cos.write(b);
            //dos.write(b);
        }

        fis.close();
        dis.close();
        //dos.close();
        cos.close();


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**Stats without encryption:**
Speed is around 27.97 MB/s
Exact Time = 25.02 sec
File Size = 700 MB

**Stats with encryption:**
Speed is around 9.69 MB/s
Exact Time = 72.171 sec
File Size = 700 MB

Comment: Have you tried a different block cypher, such as AES?

Comment: What kind of CPU do you have? When done correctly AES encryption should exceed 30MB/s even on older hardware.

Comment: I am working on CPU:  intel i3 @ 2.27 GHz
OS: Ubuntu 10.10

Comment: Newer intel i-processors have encryption instructionsets that are optimized for these kind of tasks. Maybe this will give you a huge speed boost. http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-advanced-encryption-standard-instructions-aes-ni/

Comment: @Thomas My i3 doesn't have AES instructions, but even without them I'd expect >50MB/s per core for AES on his comp.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly: if at all possible, don't do this yourself.  Encryption is very (very!) easy to mess up in ways that lead to the results being insecure.  If at all possible, use an external component or library to do as much of the encryption work as is practical.

Secondly, if you're going to do this yourself as now, don't use DES.  DES is no longer a strong-enough cipher.  Triple-DES is OK, but what you really want to be using is AES.  It's regarded as secure, modern CPUs were kept in mind during its design, you get a choice of key lengths to balance security against performance and modern CPUs have hardware acceleration for AES (AES-NI).  (I don't know whether Java uses this, but if it doesn't, it certainly might start to in future, whereas the chances of that for Triple-DES are zero.)

Thirdly, you're reading and writing a byte at a time.  Whilst encryption is going to be CPU-intensive in any event, doing it as you are at the moment is going to be slower than necessary.  Reading and writing via a `byte[]` of 4kB or so should see much better performance.

Answer (score 2):

Try wrapping the data input stream with a buffered input stream for starters.
Also check this [link](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/cryptography/ciphers.shtml) for a performance comparison of different algorithms in java. AES will indeed yield a considerably faster result than DES.

Answer (score 0):

Encryption just is CPU intensive. Maybe you can find a more efficient implementation and shave a couple of % off the run time, or use a dedicated hardware engine and get better performance for quite a few dollars.

The first thing I would ensure though is that your application is able to cope with the fact that this will just take a while. This means putting the crypto into background operations, preparing content in advance of its use and similar design considerations.

Comment: 10MB/s is very slow, even with encryption. Using multithreading and AES my i3 2.6 GHz manages 200MB/s. But I'm not familiar with the performance characteristics of DES.

Comment: @thinksteep "shaving off a few %" sounds like valid English to me. No need to fix.

Comment: @CodeInChaos AES is a good bit faster (and securer) than DES and modern CPUs have explicit HW support for AES instructions which gives tremendous speedups compared to generic HW. So not too surprising that you get 200MB/s or more there - actually it's rather low, does the i3 not support AES-NI?

Comment: At least my i3 doesn't support AES-NI. And I know that AES is much faster than TripleDES, but I don't know how it compares to plain DES.

Comment: Well, the difference is that DES is three times as fast as 3DES, I don't know if AES can match that (probably does) but DES does not provide any real encryption anyway, especially not on files that kind of size.

Comment: My old Core 2 does 62.031 MiB/s from 700 MiB byte array to itself. 10 MiB/s sounds like pretty poor buffer handling to me. Unfortunately my multithreading CTR implementation is not ready yet, no 4 core performance for me.

Comment: @CodeInChaos what kind of multithreading do you use? Simple ECB mode encryption, or some stream cipher?

Comment: When I tried with the SunJCE (I tried first with bouncy castle) I got a out of heap error, even when I had the max size set to 2G, so something seems to be pretty rotten in the JCE implementation.

Comment: The truecrypt benchmark. I think it uses 4 threads(dualcore with hyperthreading) and XTS. My old Core1 duo managed around 100MB/s if I recall correctly, but it has been a while since I used it, so I might misremember.

Comment: Ah, that would be native code, not Java code (and using counter mode encryption). Although Java is pretty fast with regard to business logic, the performance gap with optimized native AES code is pretty big (vector instructions, direct memory management). It might actually be worth it to call a native function, create a provider that uses native calculations underneath or to use the Sun PKCS#11 provider with a PKCS#11 library. None of these options for the weak of heart, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [BouncyCastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/) as an alternative? Everywhere I've seen Java cryptography used, it was used instead of the builtin APIs.